# C# : Some questions about a method which allows to display a label for a specific time

Tags: c#

I searched in google for a method which allows me to display a label for a specific time and I found this :

```
public void InfoLabel(string value)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>(InfoLabel), new object[] { value });
                return;
            }
            barStaticItem3.Caption = value;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(6000) { Enabled = true };
                timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    this.InfoLabel(string.Empty);
                    timer.Dispose();
                };
            }

        }
```

I really can't understand this method specially :

-Why we used : `InvokeRequired` ?

-What this method for : `this.Invoke()` ?

-What this is for :`new Action<string>(InfoLabel)` ?

-Why we used that sign : `=>` ?

Comment: Yay for copy pasting code from the internet. Instead of setting the label text to empty you should remove it from the form. Otherwise you will end up with tons of empty Labels on your form clogging down it's performance.

Comment: @MrFox That's not always true.  First you assume that you're dynamically adding the label.  Perhaps it's only a single status label that is set, then cleared, and set again.  That won't result in lots of labels.

Comment: Agreed, from the context it looks more like the label caption is changed rather than a new label is added, but we don't have the full source so we may never know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InvokeRequired` checks to see if the code is currently running on the thread that created the form. If it's not then the function needs to invoke itself on the thread that DID create the form as WinForms code is not threadsafe.

Action is a delegate type that describes a function that takes a string (see the InfoLabel funcion? That's what it's referring to).

```
 this.Invoke(new Action<string>(InfoLabel), new object[] { value });
```

The above is saying. Please create a new delegate of type Action from the function InfoLabel and invoke it using the thread that created this. When you invoke it pass the object 'value' to it. ie call InfoLabel(value) on the thread that created the form. Notice that it returns from the function directly afterwards so none of the 'meat' of the function is run on the wrong thread (we are on the wrong thread at this point, otherwise InvokeRequired would not have been true). When the function is run again by Invoke it will be on the right thread and InvokeRequired will be false so this bit of code will not be run.

```
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    this.InfoLabel(string.Empty);
                    timer.Dispose();
                };
```

The above code is assigning an anonymous method to the Elapsed event of the timer. The first bit (sender, args) is describing the parameters of the method, then `=>` is saying 'here comes the method', followed by a block of code (all the stuff inside the brackets).

Comment: In a regular WinForms application you will have a thread that runs the Main function. If you look in that function it calls something like Run(new Form1()) or something like that. That's where the form is created and the thread that does it is the one that owns the form. Anything that wants to alter the form (or for the most part its controls - since they are generally created when the form is created) should make sure to do so on that thread.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.. I see that DID is an abbreviation for some term what's that term ?

Comment: Oh, sorry - No I put 'did' in capital letters to emphasise the word. It's not an abbreviation or anything.

Answer (score 4):

All of the invoke related stuff is because the person who write that code used the wrong `Timer` (there are quite a few in the language).  You should be using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` here.

```
public void InfoLabel(string value)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.Interval = 1000;//or whatever the time should be.
    timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            label1.Text = value;
            timer.Stop();
        };
    timer.Start();
}
```

The forms timer will have code inside of it's own implementation that does something similar to the code that is in your sample (although I find it to be a particularly messy way of doing so).  It will ensure that the `Tick` event runs in the UI thread so that you don't need to add in all of that boilerplate code.

The `=>` is a lambda expression.  It's a way of defining a new anonymous method that takes two parameters `sender` and `args`.

You could also use `Task`s to solve this problem, rather than using timers:

```
public void InfoLabel2(string value)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000)) //could use Task.Delay if you have 4.5
        .ContinueWith(task => label1.Text = value
            , CancellationToken.None
            , TaskContinuationOptions.None
            , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: I think he means to make the label invisible after the given time, instead of showing the text from then on.

Comment: @MrFox You could do that using this method.  Just set the label text to what you want before calling this and then pass in an empty string to this method.  This covers the general case.

Comment: +1 for the mention of the forms timer - though I don't trust it :D

Answer (score 3):

Many questions!

`InvokeRequired` is due to the multi-threaded nature of applications. A UI based application has a UI thread on which all the updates for the user interface are done. Updating a member of the control from a non-UI thread will throw a cross thread exception, using Invoke will marshal the update to the UI thread - which is legal.

The `Action<string>` is a delegate for a method, it will call the InfoLabel method when the delegate is called with the passed in arguments - e.g. action.Invoke("someString"). The => is a lambda expression which is used to create an anonymous method (e.g. a method with no name) which will be run instead of pointing to a named method

Comment: I like Sergeys explanation better haha :D

Comment: Thanks, but yours deserves +1 as well IMHO :)

Answer (score 2):

`InvokeRequired` is used to check whether we call the method `InfoLabel` from the UI thread where `barStaticItem3` control persists. If the thread is different (InvokeRequired) then the same method is called with `this.Invoke(new Action<string>(InfoLabel), new object[] { value });` - this calls the same method from within UI thread.

```
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.InfoLabel(string.Empty);
                timer.Dispose();
            };
```

This code creates an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28VS.80%29.aspx) which is then called on `timer`'s `Elapsed` event. Practically this clears the label after 6 seconds (timer's interval on costruction) and disposes of `timer` object so that this anonymous method is called only once.